# Send json object data with input file to node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, file

How can someone send json object and input file on the same request. I am familiar with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655582/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-jquery-ajax) and others.I don't use a `<form>` element as a parent of the `<input type="file">` element but just a div. My code is like this:

```
var inputFiles = document.getElementById('archiveFile').files[0]
var formData = new FormData(); // Currently empty
formData.append('file[]',inputFiles,'hey.png')//append the input file



var data= { p_doc_no: "some value",
            p_receive_date: "some value1",
            p_thema: "some value2",
            p_prot_no: "some value3",
            p_sender: "some value4",
            p_energeia: "some value5",
        }
```

I have tried appending the object in the formData like this:

```
for ( var key in data ) {
    formData.append(key, data[key]);
}
```

and then make the AJAX request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'makeDBEntry/archive',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

but no luck until now. Any thoughts? At the end i need to access the request data from node js

**Update**
Thanks to [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) I have found my silly solution as easy as using the multer module to handle formdata in node js

Comment: Your client side approach seems fine. Problem is likely server side assuming url path is correct, input id is correct etc. What errors are you getting from the ajax and in your node console?

Comment: my req.body property is empty and also when i try to save the file with the multer module the req.fiiles is also undefined would you like to upload the server side?

Comment: are you using correct body parser? Have you tried this using a simple form and no ajax?

Comment: I am usin JSON ..

Comment: but you aren't sending json, you are sending formData