# Send file with JSON Data in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to send a image file to a the Controller but `HttpPostedFileBase` is null and I enter `image: image` outside  `JSON.stringify({})` but not worked.
Also, I change `contentType`and see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655582/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-jquery-ajax) and use it answer but my problem not fixed.

```
var file_data = $("#Image").prop("files")[0];   
var image = new FormData();

image.append("file", file_data);

$.ajax({
        url: '@postUrl',
        method: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data:
            JSON.stringify({
                    image: image,
                    isFirst : true,
                    ExternalProjects: ExternalProjects,
                    // more data

            })
       })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not put the `FormData` instance within an object and stringify it. You do the opposite: put your file(s) and other data in the FormData instance.

And as the answer you linked to says change the `contentType` and `processData` options to false to tell jQuery not to process the data itself.

```
var file_data = $("#Image").prop("files")[0];   
var fd = new FormData();

fd.append("file", file_data);
fd.append("isFirst", true);
fd.append("ExternalProjects", ExternalProjects);
$.ajax({
    url: '@postUrl',
    method: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data:fd
});
```

Your data will be in the respective fields: `file`, `isFirst`, and `ExternalProjects`

Comment: thanks your answer. got this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh, oops, accidently made the `false` a string and not the actual boolean value `false`. Simply remove the quotes around `false`, updated answer to reflect

Comment: How does one access the respective fields?

Comment: @user8016906 that would depend on the backend and how it parses requests. Specifically for asp I do not know as I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

The best wat I discovered for myself:

```
export const convertDataToFormDataFormat = (data, formData = null, keyPrefix = '') => {
  if (!data) {
    return null;
  }

  let currentFormData = formData || new FormData();
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    data.forEach((entry, i) => {
      currentFormData = convertDataToFormDataFormat(entry, currentFormData, `${keyPrefix}[${i}].`);
    });

    return currentFormData;
  }

  if (data) {
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      const fullKey = keyPrefix + key;
      if (value === undefined || value === null) {
        currentFormData.append(fullKey, '');
      } else if (value.constructor === File) {
        currentFormData.append(fullKey, value);
      } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        currentFormData = convertDataToFormDataFormat(value, currentFormData, `${fullKey}`);
      } else if (value === Object(value)) {
        currentFormData = convertDataToFormDataFormat(value, currentFormData, `${fullKey}.`);
      } else {
        currentFormData.append(fullKey, value);
      }
    });
  }

  return currentFormData;
};
```

Converts to something like this:

```
fieild.test1= 'test';
fieild.test2= 'test';
field.arr[0].testField1 = 'testField ';
field.arr[0].testField2 = 'testField ';
field.arr[1].testField = 'testField ';
field.arr[1].testField2 = 'testField ';
field.arr[2].testField = 'testField ';
field.arr[2].testField2 = 'testField ';
```

Works great for asp.net core 2.0:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateExpense([FromForm] List<SomeModelWithIFormFileField> dto)
{
    ....
}
```